# unable to read file using logstash (issue with input plugin)

Tags: logstash

I am new to logstash on ubuntu. I am using file plugin in the input where I have given the path for displaying the content of the file on the stdout.This is my configuration file
        `input{
          file{
             path =>"/home/om/Desktop/app/logstash/logstash-1.4.22/logs.txt"
             start_position => "beginning"
             }
            }
         output{
             stdout{}
             }`

I am not getting any output on the console. I want to dump the data from the .txt file on the console.

Comment: can you provide your configuration file?

Comment: I have added the configuration file. I am not getting any error but a {;level=>warn} that "Using milestone 2 input plugin 'file'. This plugin is stable....."  what might have gone wrong?

Comment: Try setting your sincedb_path to /dev/null.

Comment: I tried using sincedb_path => /dev/null    I can see a file by name 'null' created but still I don't see output on my console. Where can be the problem?

Comment: Which version of logstash you are using??

Answer (score 0):

**Use this configuration:**

```
  input {

        file {

          path => [ "\\IpAddress\logs/filename.*.*_bak"" ]
          start_position => "beginning"     

         }
     }
    output {

        elasticsearch {
                bind_host => "127.0.0.1"
                port => "9200"
                protocol => http
           }
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }

     }
```

**And also checking with below commands:**

```
>logstash --configtest -f logstash.conf --> for configuration testing
>logstash --debug -f logstash.conf --> for debugging
```